# JavaFX with Maven

Tags: maven-2, maven, javafx

I recently started a JavaFX project, and I'd like to use Maven as my compiler/deployment tool.

Is there a good tutorial or plugin to integrate JavaFX and Maven?

Comment: Guide with instructions for Maven: https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#introduction

Answer (score 12):

Starting with Java 7u9 I think JavaFX is shipped together with Java SE runtime and the rest, so it makes it pretty easy to create a Maven-based JavaFX project.

Here is what you do (assuming you have latest Java SE 7 runtime environment):

1. Go to directory where your JRE libs are installed: `cd "/c/Program
   Files/Java/jre7/lib"`
2. Find what is the version of the JavaFX by reading the *javafx.properties* file. `cat javafx.properties` will produce something like: `javafx.runtime.version=2.2.3`
3. Now you are ready to install the JavaFX runtime package to Maven: `mvn install:install-file -Dfile=jfxrt.jar -DgroupId=com.oracle -DartifactId=javafx -Dpackaging=jar -Dversion=2.2.3`
4. Finally, create a simple Maven project, in say NetBeans, open your pom.xml file and add the following dependency:

---

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
  <artifactId>javafx</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.3</version>
</dependency>
```

---

Once you save the pom.xml you can continue using your typical Maven workflow.

Please note I used the MSYS (http://www.mingw.org) environment on Windows in the examples above in the case you get confused. If you prefer Windows CMD it would be very much similar. I just do not feel comfortable without BASH and GNU tools such as sed, grep, etc...

Comment: I much prefer Reyman's answer of using a [dedicated JavaFX maven plugin](https://github.com/zonski/javafx-maven-plugin) to the solution presented in this answer - or just use Oracle Java 8+ and JavaFX will work out of the box (just like the rest of the JRE), no plugin or maven dependency information required.  If you follow the instructions in this answer you may end up with issues like [JavaFX can't load caspian.css](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20623979/javafx-cant-load-caspian-css)

Comment: I think this approach is ok. However, one might need to add provided scope or `<optional>true</optional>` to dependency declaration.

Answer (score 4):

This helped me a lot:

[Blog Entry](http://karussell.wordpress.com/2009/03/29/javafx-and-maven/)

In the beginning of the Blog Entry the author mentions another great Article that can be found here...:

[Another Blog](http://blog.nelsonsilva.eu/2008/10/10/javafx-maven-on-ubuntu/)

The main "magic" is getting "settings.xml" right...
Afterwards...it is not that difficult.

Answer (score 3):

I released a new version of the FEST JavaFX Compiler Maven Plug-in. This new version supports compilation of test sources. For more details please visit http://alexruiz.developerblogs.com/?p=1197

Comment: It looks that this plug-in is not in active development any more.

Answer (score 3):

There is a maven plugin developped by an user of javafx.

See this mailling post :

http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/openjfx-dev/2012-October/003969.html

and the github site :

https://github.com/zonski/javafx-maven-plugin

Answer (score 2):

Alex Ruiz had a really good post on this recently and released a Maven plugin that should help you:

http://alexruiz.developerblogs.com/?p=725

Comment: Looks like the link is broken.