# How to make maven consider JavaFX as a part of JRE

Tags: maven, javafx

I experimenting with JavaFX. Since JDK 1.7 JavaFX is now part of JRE, however, when I run maven install and don't specify system dependency with system dependency compilation is failed because JavaFX classes are not found. Is there a way to make maven consider JavaFX as a part of JDK?

Comment: Here is how I do it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14961720/876497

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For now, keep jfxrt.jar as a system dependency as you have doing.

As of jdk7u6, even though jfxrt.jar is in the jdk's jre/lib directory, JavaFX is not on the default java classpath due to potential compatability concerns for non-JavaFX programs.  In later jdk releases, JavaFX will be added to the default jdk classpath and it will no longer be necessary to specify JavaFX as a maven system dependency for your project.

Comment: Perhaps nothing - I think Oracle are being conservative about their release strategy.