# JavaFX can't load caspian.css

Tags: maven, javafx

I have a Maven project in which I use a `javaxf` WebEngine. I first included `javafx` by installing [e(fx)clipse](http://www.eclipse.org/efxclipse/index.html), and I was able to use it normally.

Now I want to compile my program to a big .jar file with all dependencies included. I first used a `<scope>system</scope>` and linked to the `jfxrt.jar` in my JDK (1.7.0_45). I compile my program using `mvm package` and it works well for the build part.

Then, I installed the `jfxrt.jar` in maven thanks to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14961720) so I have a `javafx-2.2.45.jar` with maven.

However, I'm stuck with this error when I **run** my program and when it comes to instantiate that particular WebEngine:

```
INFO: com.sun.javafx.css.StyleManager loadStylesheetUnPrivileged Could not find     stylesheet: jar:file:/target/project-name-0.1.one-jar.jar!/lib/javafx-2.2.45.jar!/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/caspian/caspian.css
SEVERE: javafx.scene.control.Control impl_processCSS The -fx-skin property has not been  defined in CSS for ScrollBarThemeImpl$ScrollBarWidget@5919e0a8[styleClass=scroll-bar]
java.lang.NullPointerException
  at com.sun.webpane.sg.theme.ScrollBarThemeImpl.initializeThickness(ScrollBarThemeImpl.java:341)
  at com.sun.webpane.sg.theme.ScrollBarThemeImpl.access$100(ScrollBarThemeImpl.java:27)
  at com.sun.webpane.sg.theme.ScrollBarThemeImpl$ScrollBarWidget.impl_updatePG(ScrollBarThemeImpl.java:50)
  at javafx.scene.Node.impl_syncPGNode(Node.java:425)
  at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.syncAll(Scene.java:2106)
  at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.syncAll(Scene.java:2115)
  at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.syncAll(Scene.java:2115)
  at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.synchronizeSceneNodes(Scene.java:2082)
  at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.pulse(Scene.java:2193)
  at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.firePulse(Toolkit.java:363)
  at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:463)
  at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit$9.run(QuantumToolkit.java:332)
  at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:76)
```

I opened this jar and was able to find the `caspian.css` file where it's supposed to be.

What should I do to be able to use my WebEngine in my "big compiled jar"? I don't care if the solution is a quick, dirty fix such as copy/paste of this css file somewhere else (I already tried that but I might have missed something..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a good idea to package fx into your jar. Have you tried using http://www.zenjava.com/2013/07/01/javafx-maven-plugin-2-0-released/

Comment: I did not. It seemed to me this was for building a javafx-only application, but in my app, it's only a part of the app. I'll give it a shot. However, I need this jar to be a standalone, so I need javafx to be bundled into it...

Comment: Ok it worked! Awesome, thanks. Had a bit of a struggle to use it, but it's done. You made my day :)

Answer (score 0):

You might need to declare your dependency like for not to include JavaFX into the uber jar. You could also exclude javafx packages from when creating this jar, but I don't think it's recommended as in theory resources might not be placed under the javafx package.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
  <artifactId>javafx</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.3</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

or

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
  <artifactId>javafx</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.3</version>
  <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

Update: the is also a javafx maven plugin as @tomsontom mentioned.

Comment: Indeed, @tomsontom's way was the one to go. Thank you.